# Which preposition is correct to the following context?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct to the following context? 
I want to write to my friend to read the story and to answer questions which comes after the story. Now the options that I can think about are:

> "Read the following story and answer the questions **afterward**"
>
> "Read the following story and answer the **following questions**" (too
>   much "following")
>
> "Read the following story and answer the questions **follow this story**"

Which style is correct or common and easy to understand, if any? or you have other suggestion for my need.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. In the sense of time flow, *afterward/afterwards* is better. It would be the same as *after that*.

> Read the following story and answer the questions **after that**.

In the sense of location, *follow* is better. I think you mean the latter, so maybe

> Read the following story and answer the questions **that follow**.